# Magento getting different results for sales order reports

Tags: magento-1.9

I am checking magento sales order reports. When I add the same date range in reports and sales order grid (purchased date). But I am getting different result for them.

Can anyone tell me what is the reason for this and what I can do to solve the issue.

Thank You

Comment: did you refresh the order reports statistics?

Comment: Yes, i refreshed it. But did not work.